# Getting values from a url in python(3)

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am trying to host a small webserver that gets field values from a url request. I am sure I have phrased this question incorrectly, so here is an example:

The user should be able to go to a url like: http://webserverurl.com/index.html&variable=34355&variable2=3445

The server should save both values in two variables, and print them to the console, like:

Got: variable is 34355, variable2 is 3445

Would this be possible to do in flask, or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exemple URL could be `http://webserverurl.com/index.html?variable=34355&variable2=3445` (I used "?" and not "&" between ressources and GET parameters).

You can to it with flask, GET parameters are accessed by

```
from flask import request
request.args.get('key', '')
```

I suggest you to read this :  http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/